# Json response undefined using AJAX in Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, symfony

I am working with Symfony 2.0, trying to call an Action thru ajax
I've checked the Action response and returns Json (OK). But when I call it from ajax, I recieve a String containing all the html of the twig.

This is my js code:

```
    var askPassword = function(){
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#formUpdate").attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data.success);
            console.log(data);
            //alert(typeof(data)); /*returns String!!! why??*/
        },
    });
};
```

This is my php code:

```
public function checkPasswordAction(){
    $jsonArray = array(
        'success'=> "hola",
        'message'=> "como",
        'result' => "estas");
    $jsonResponse = json_encode($jsonArray);
    $response = new Response($jsonResponse);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

It is weird, but if I uncomment **the dataType: "json"** in the ajax call, then the action never gets called.

I'm at a point that I can't see where it might be the problem. Please help

Comment: Are you sure the action never gets called? dataType: "json" sets the expectation that the data returned to be strict JSON. I suspect what is happening is your ajax is firing just fine, but your JSON is failing validation.

Comment: no, the ajax call doesn't executes and the data type returned is always String

Answer (score 0):

I am using this syntax and its working fine for me.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode(array(
    'data' => 123,
)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```